# How to change between controllers when button tapped , iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

So i have my main viewController and all i have is a single button inside.
The code of the button is :

```
- (IBAction)eventsButton:(id)sender {
self.eventsViewController =[[EventsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EventsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:eventsViewController animated:YES];}
```

where EventsViewController is another controller where i want to navigate when this button is clicked. But when i click it nothing happens.. I dont navigate to the other controller.

```
ViewController.h
-------------------
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class EventsViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>

- (IBAction)eventsButton:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) EventsViewController *eventsViewController;


@end




ViewController.m
-----------------
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "EventsViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize eventsViewController;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)eventsButton:(id)sender {
    self.eventsViewController =[[EventsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EventsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventsViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

I put a breakpoint in the IBACTION and i see that the code is executed , but it never navigates me to the other controller. The other controller is just a simple controller i created with Xcode , it has all the code Xcode gives and nothing mine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you didn't put ViewController inside UINavigationController. First you have to alloc and init UINavigationController. So inside `application: didFinishLounchingWithOptions:`

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController]
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]
```

It should work.

Comment: And if i dont want the navigation bar on my main controller i ll just put this line on the ViewWillAppear method : [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    and in the other controllers i ll put YES. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:eventsViewController animated:YES];
```

its works only current view controller is navigation controller.Actually you implement this code in normal view controller not in navigation controller. Check with this following code replace above line

```
[self presentModalViewController:eventsViewController animated:YES];
```

So You need to implement navigation controller for your current view controller. In Appdelegate you change root view controller to navigation controller with your view controller.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourController] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```